# The usage of study to be or learn to be. Can you say study to be a hairdresser?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I had a discussion with my colleagues about studying and learning.

I thought that you can say studying to be a hairdresser and not learning to be one. Or can you? Is it the same?

The problem is the word study and my colleagues think that involves only the studying to be a doctor, for example. That you don't really "study" to be a hairdresser.

Thanks

Comment: You do if you're going to a cosmetology school.

Comment: This is a grey area. 'Study to be a ...' is usually reserved for the more academic professions like teacher, surgeon, physicist, astronomer.... It's a judgement call as to whether 'hairdresser' is in this domain. There _are_ quite a few examples on the internet, and courses of study are certainly run.

Comment: I think a clear line could be if there was a book or written material involved... perhaps even video material if the videos were broken into segments covering theory, types of dyes and how to mix them etc.   To the extent the person was receiving practical lessons in use of tools, "training" would be more appropriate.  A doctor ~studying medicine~ could also ~train to be a surgeon~ .  "Studying hairdressing" is a bit much. as it is the practice not the knowledge, but as @Laurel points out, "cosmetology" entails more specific knowledge.

Comment: learning [a language] versus studying to be a [professional something.  An engineering student might study plumbing but a plumber had better damn well learn it to be a plumber. Even if you study to be a doctor, you also have to learn to be one. I shall have to think about this learn/study a bit more.

Comment: "Learning" is a broader term yet it has it's focus.  "Learning about" is a bit different from "learning x" too.  "I am learning to Spanish" conveys more the ability to converse in verbally and/or reading and writing. "Studying Spanish tonight" might be time spent understanding verb conjugations one night but "Studying Spanish" more broadly would imply understanding the language with at least some regards to linguistics, culture, history etc. (at least to me). Training to be a Spanish interpreter,  would entail both a facility with the language and some applied social/work skills

Comment: @Lambie .. there is also a distinction between "learn to" and "learn about" .  The first a practice and the second more similar to 'study' although a  bit less formal.  In the absense of a "to" and the use of a gerund "learn plumbing"  it implies "learn to be a plumber" or "learn to do plumbing" in my opinion .. what the shorthand omits is important.

Comment: @Tom22 I am a quadri-lingual interpreter and translator and am also English mother tongue. Believe me, I know the score.  I agree with you, of course, that earn x, learn to x and learn about x are all different.

Comment: @Lambie I was just expanding, not correcting. : )  I really think these types of comments that paint nuances of usage help and make this site more like the SE computing questions where not only an "answer" but best practices and alternatives are given to coding questions.

Comment: @Tom22 I getcha. No worries. But I'm thinking that maybe I can some up with a semantic trait that will divide them such that "learning to be a doctor" and "studying to be a doctor" become clearer. See what I mean? I'm very into that as a mental exercise, and, often, one can come up with some interesting tidbits....

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/study Study is not a technical term, nor is it jargon. You can **study** virtually anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Studying to be a hairdresser is perfectly fine. You will find some community misconceptions though that there will be no academic aspect as well as plenty of academic snobbery.

Studying as a term works perfectly well in a trade when engaging in a theoretical exercise (e.g. researching current styles trends, techniques and market analysis for tools) or one of observation (e.g. watching an experienced hair dresser at work).

Learn and train can be used too. You'll find the latter more commonly used when reffering to a trade.

Comment: I wrote a very long post which I deleted.  Your answer hits the points more concisely.  The dictionary definition of "study" includes the word "academic" - however,  how generously we apply that word is one of "perspective" (or snobbery) .  When your friends are Doctors, Lawyers or professors, or if you read 'white papers' and rue the amateur knowledge of reporters even at the NYT or WSJ,  it is easy to discount even upper division undergraduate courses at an elite university of a being a bit short of "academic", but to a housekeeper, learning of dyes and hair follicles qualifies.